Java Fatal Error Preventing Liferay from Running in Eclipse
I run Liferay 7.4 in Eclipse. I have been using the same environment now for 6 months and everything has worked perfectly. However, about two weeks ago, I started getting a fatal Java error after starting Liferay in Eclipse.
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000001bdc1b2dfd0, pid=14556, tid=14852

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (11.0.13+10) (build 11.0.13+10-LTS-370)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (11.0.13+10-LTS-370, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
Problematic frame:
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.equalsIgnoreCase(Ljava/lang/String;)Z+21

No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

I had been able to clean Liferay out and restart it and sometimes it would work. However, it has gotten progressively worse and now won't start successfully at all.
I read some other posts that suggest this could be tied to a 3rd party library or driver, but I don't know how to trace the error back to it.
TIA.

Please use code format for code, errors and logs. But take into account that this site is not for supporting applications running on Java. It is for programming questions including for the Java language.
